# Spring Boot app, content served and app functioning fine but getting a lot of 'Did not find handler method for *...' spam

Tags: spring-boot

I've got a few Spring Boot web apps that are functioning fine, but I get a ton of spam related to 'Did not find handler method for X' since using Spring Boot 2.0.4. I get it for static content as well. This is a Spring Boot 2.0.4/Thymeleaf app. It's not affecting the functionality of the app at all as all content is being served but it's quite annoying. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to filter it out through logging.level.org.springframework.boot=INFO.